# What are the 22 possible values of x where x== -x (true)?

Tags: java

Recently this question asked in Java interview. Tried and searched the solution but can't find. kindly, comment the solution if anybody knows. It would be helpful.

Comment: What's the domain? Real numbers?

Comment: Zeroes in the numeric basic types. Float and double have two zeroes each. That's nine values. Then there's `MIN_VALUE` for int and long. That's eleven. I can't think of any more.

Comment: @khelwood The wrappers could count too, perhaps. That makes it 22, right?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I think that's the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Zeroes in the numeric basic types. Float and double have two zeroes each. That's nine values. Then there's `MIN_VALUE` for int and long. That's eleven.

So:

```
int x = 0;
int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
long x = 0;
long x = Long.MIN_VALUE;
byte x = 0;
short x = 0;
char x = 0;
double x = 0.0;
double x = -0.0;
float x = 0f;
float x = -0f;
```

Then each of those values wrapped as an object:

```
Integer x = 0;
Integer x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Long x = 0L;
Long x = Long.MIN_VALUE;
Byte x = 0;
Short x = 0;
Character x = 0;
Double x = 0.0;
Double x = -0.0;
Float x = 0f;
Float x = -0f;
```

That's 22 total.

(I wouldn't have called the objects more *values*. They're the same 11 values again but wrapped in objects. But if you're supposed to find 22 total, I think this must be it.)

Note that for smaller integral types, like short, performing `-x` would widen them to an int, so `x==-x` does not work for `Short.MIN_VALUE`.

`x==-x` evaluates as true for floating-point zeroes, because even though positive zero and negative zero are different values, they are regarded as equal to each other.

Comment: What about `var x = 0`, in that case? Does that count as the 23rd?  Or maybe the 22½th? (using Java 10 local variable type inference).

Comment: @andrewjames `var x = 0;` gives you an int. It is equivalent to `int x = 0;`

Comment: Understood (hence "22½th") - but what is the meaning of "value" in the question's title, in that case? Does Java have a specific meaning for that term, which means both the number and the type/primitive holding that number? I assumed that "value" means "0" not `int x = 0;`.